# How to traverse all unamed metadata in a LLVM module?

Tags: llvm

After reading LLVM API documentation, I know how to traverse named metadata.

But I wonder how to traverse unamed metadata.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey Napolean, stack overflow is a great place to get help with code! Are you able to edit this question to show what code you have tried? If you need assistance in formatting and how to ask the perfect question here is a link to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.I will revise my description of the question.